# Which ASP.net Authentication/Membership Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, wif

I am about to begin building a new ASP.net Web Forms application.  I had read quite a bit about the new [ASP.net Identity System](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) and chose this as the default option when creating a new Web Forms solution.

I was surprised by two things:

1. The lack of features baked into the standard system, particularly when compared to the older ASP.net Membership service.  This I could live with (if I had to!), if it wasn't for...
2. The lack of documentation/documented examples on how to implement a standard/simple membership service with the new ASP.net Identity framework.

I did come across an article on [Migrating an Existing Website from SQL Membership to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity), but this seemed like a lot of effort (maybe I've just become lazy when it comes to implementing Membership services!).

Can anyone recommend any resources that clearly explain how to implement ASP.net Identity?  Or are people still using the older Membership systems or something else?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Lack? you really need to read MSDN! All you need it's there, plus in dozens of blog posts... or simply follow up the link that the class provides you..

Comment: @balexandre, yes lack. v1 is basically unusable: http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/

Comment: I did spend several hours looking through MSDN and searching in general.  Whilst I admit I may not have the best search technique and it is quite possible that I missed something, all I really found were articles extolling the virtues of the new Identity service and quite a lot of blog posts with code to address specific issues.  Nowhere have a found documentation that demonstrates its implementation in a 'typical' web application similar to that performed by the original Membership service.  Maybe the answer is that you have to 'roll your own' solution - I was just expecting more clarity.

Comment: I use my own version of ASP.NET Identity and I have no complains...

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer, but perhaps a explanation...

I was expecting the new ASP.net Identity service to be a replacement/upgrade of the older Membership service - which I have been using for several years.  After much searching and reading, I do not believe that it is a replacement, at least, not yet.

From what I can see, it appears to be 'just' a foundation layer for building your own membership system.  Out of the box, it doesn't appear to manage account validation, password retries or any of the other things that you, or at least I, would expect/need to developing a public web application.

If you want to build you own Membership system, then this is fine, but at this point I didn't (although the amount of time I have spent researching this and playing with various extensions that I have found from blog posts etc, I probably could have done!).

For more background and a possible quicker and easier alternative, see the post by Brock Allen [The good, the bad and the ugly of ASP.NET Identity](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/).